# Apache SSL virtual host doesn't respond (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Tags: ssl-certificate, virtualhost, https

I am a noob apache admin, please be patient!

I have an Apache server on a single IP hosting a number of virtual hosts on http. I am now trying to install certificates to enable HTTPS but am having no success.

The `conf` file looks like this:

```
Listen 443
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so

NameVirtualHost www.mark3technologies.com:443
<VirtualHost www.mark3technologies.com:443>
    DocumentRoot "<path>/mark3technologies"
    ServerName www.mark3technologies.com
    ServerAlias mark3technologies.com
    ServerAdmin craig@mark3technologies.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "<path>/mark3technologies.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "<path>/mark3technologies.com.key"
    SSLCaCertificateFile "<path>/AlphaSSL_SHA-256R1IntCert.crt"
    <Directory "<path>/mark3technologies">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
SSLSessionCache shmcb:/etc/httpd/ssl_scache(512000)
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCompression off

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "<path>/mark3technologies"
    ServerName www.mark3technologies.com
    ServerAlias mark3technologies.com
    ServerAdmin craig@mark3technologies.com
    <Directory "<path>/mark3technologies">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

`apachectl -S` also looks reasonable...

```
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release <path>/vserver.conf:44
VirtualHost configuration:
54.247.123.104:443     www.mark3technologies.com (<path>/vserver.conf:45)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server cdmh.co.uk (<path>/vserver.conf:12)
         port 80 namevhost cdmh.co.uk (<path>/vserver.conf:12)
                 alias cdmh.co.uk
                 alias craighenderson.co.uk
                 wild alias *.cdmh.co.uk
                 wild alias *.craighenderson.co.uk
         port 80 namevhost runmotivator.com (<path>/vserver.conf:28)
                 alias runmotivator.com
                 wild alias *.runmotivator.com
         port 80 namevhost www.mark3technologies.com (<path>/vserver.conf:71)
                 alias mark3technologies.com
         port 80 namevhost www.sonningcommonmagazine.com (<path>/vserver.conf:86)
                 alias sonningcommonmagazine.org
                 wild alias *.sonningcommonmagazine.org
                 wild alias *.sonningcommonmagazine.com
```

The `error.log` reads like it is working Ok.

```
AH01914: Configuring server www.mark3technologies.com:443 for SSL protocol
ssl_engine_init.c(1665): AH: Init: (www.mark3technologies.com:443) mod_md support is unavailable.
ssl_engine_init.c(1949): AH02209: CA certificate: CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE
ssl_engine_init.c(492): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
ssl_util_ssl.c(470): AH02412: [www.mark3technologies.com:443] Cert matches for name 'www.mark3technologies.com' [subject: CN=www.mark3technologies.com,OU=Domain Control Validated / issuer: CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE / serial: 016DD49AA34CB94BA2610089 / notbefore: Oct 28 14:01:28 2019 GMT / notafter: Oct 28 14:01:28 2020 GMT]
AH02568: Certificate and private key www.mark3technologies.com:443:0 configured from /home/ubuntu/www/sites/mark3technologies.com.crt and /home/ubuntu/www/sites/mark3technologies.com.key
AH01914: Configuring server www.mark3technologies.com:443 for SSL protocol
ssl_engine_init.c(1665): AH: Init: (www.mark3technologies.com:443) mod_md support is unavailable.
ssl_engine_init.c(1949): AH02209: CA certificate: CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE
ssl_engine_init.c(492): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
ssl_util_ssl.c(470): AH02412: [www.mark3technologies.com:443] Cert matches for name 'www.mark3technologies.com' [subject: CN=www.mark3technologies.com,OU=Domain Control Validated / issuer: CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE / serial: 016DD49AA34CB94BA2610089 / notbefore: Oct 28 14:01:28 2019 GMT / notafter: Oct 28 14:01:28 2020 GMT]
AH02568: Certificate and private key www.mark3technologies.com:443:0 configured from /home/ubuntu/www/sites/mark3technologies.com.crt and /home/ubuntu/www/sites/mark3technologies.com.key
AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1a configured -- resuming normal operations
AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

When I browse to the site on HTTP all is Ok, but with HTTPS the server does not respond, and I get no errors at all.

Firewall:

```
$ sudo ufw status
WARN: Duplicate profile 'Apache', using last found
WARN: Duplicate profile 'Apache Secure', using last found
WARN: Duplicate profile 'Apache Full', using last found
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

It looks like I'm tantilisingly close; what is the final hurdle to overcome, please?

Comment: Checked your firewall?

Comment: yes, allow 80,443 TCP/IP

Comment: Asduming linux What does "sudo fuser -n tcp 443" say? This looks to check that Apache is listening on port 443.

Comment: @davidgo yes, linux :) output is `443/tcp:             15536 15554 15557 15558 15575 15704 15715 15717 15718 18604 18606`

Comment: In that case, notwithstanding your concerns, this sounds VERY much like a firewall issue.  What happens if you run the command "sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT" ?

Comment: @davidgo no output from that command :(

Comment: Wouldn't have expected output - I would expect it to open up port 443 on the firewall - what happens if you try connect after running that command?

Comment: Also, what IP address does "ping www.mark3technologies.com" return from the server?

Comment: Ah, ok! No change in trying to browse to https. I've added the firewall output to the question above. `PING www.mark3technologies.com (54.247.123.104) 56(84) bytes of data`